# Arduino: Controlling two dc motors through radio

Tags: c++, arduino, motordriver, radio-transmission

What I am trying to do is to remotely control two DC motors via 433MHz transmission.

Sending the data of the joystick works fine. Receiving it also works fine. But I must have something wrong with my drivers because when I connect my wires the receiver stops working (if I disconnect them it works fine).

This is the receiver:

[Frizing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUT65.jpg)

The NPN transistors are 547B, and the motors draw around 150mA with 5V.

The code I have for the receiver is the following:

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>

char recibo[8]="";

int valorX=0;
int valorY=0;


void setup(){
  
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT); 
  
  vw_set_ptt_inverted(true); // Required for DR3100
  vw_set_rx_pin(12);
  vw_setup(4000);  // Bits per sec
  vw_rx_start();       // Start the receiver PLL running
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("setup");
}
void loop(){
  uint8_t buf[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
  uint8_t buflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;
  if (vw_get_message(buf, &buflen)){ //check to see if anything has been received
    for(int i=0;i<buflen;i++){ //guardo los datos recibidos en un arra
      recibo[i]=char(buf[i]);
    }
    recibo[buflen]=NULL; //Necesario para obtener el string correcto (finalizacion de array)
    sscanf( recibo, "%d,%d", &valorX, &valorY ); //Con esto tengo guardadas en las dos variables los datos recibidos de los sensores

    int mappedValueX=map(valorX, 500, 1000, 0, 255);
    
    if(mappedValueX>150){
      analogWrite(5,mappedValueX);
      delay(15);
      analogWrite(6,mappedValueX);
      delay(15);
    }
    else{
      analogWrite(5,0);
      delay(15);
      analogWrite(6,0);
      delay(15);
    }
  } 
}
```

If I connect the motors (they take the power from an external battery), the arduino stops receiving data, and when I disconnect them, it starts immediately to receive data again.

It must be some kind of interference, and in those topics I am terribly lost.

Comment: Ignoring the radio for the moment, can you control both or one motor with, e.g. a fixed PWM value? Have you tried putting some 10 or 100uF decoupling caps across the +5/0v on the breadboard? How about if you replace the motors with LEDs, can you control their brightness?

Comment: is that a 100 ohm resistor in series with the base of the transistors? say the Arduino output goes up to 2.7V that's 20mA base current - shouldn't need to be such a low resistor, make it 470 ohms.

Comment: I had a similar experience with motors, they produce a lot of noise. you need to filter this noise out.

Comment: Yes barny, I made the motors work without using the radio first and they work fine (before that I also tried the dimming of the leds and it also worked).

Comment: I tried changing the resistance for 470 ohms and the same happened. Using a 680 ohms the receiver works, but the motors dont get enough current. When the motors dont get enough current, the receiver stops again. I have been thinking that maybe I need more transistors to make a Darlington pair and get more current. I guess this excludes noise from the problem right?

Comment: Also tried the capacitor and same result, only now it does not work even with 680 ohms

Comment: with powerful enough motors you have to use optronic elements to achieve galvanic isolation of power circuit from logic. Also, depending on type of motor, they can produce quite a bit of interference in close proximity, are they brushless? Are they shielded?